# Extracting data from a field in Sage 50 into an application

Tags: c#, opayo, sage-erp, sage50

This isn't so much a question but more so a "Could someone please point me in the right direction".

I have been given a task at work to bring across some data in a field from a product in Sage 50 into our application (written in C# for reference). The information is static and will not be used for any form of calculation, it is just a description of a product, IE Pack of 10.

I have never done anything with Sage before and I was wondering if someone could shed some light on which direction I would need to go for this.

Comment: can u please know me how to find Or Calculate Product's cost, sale price, and Quantity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Sage ODBC Driver then use classes from [System.Data.Odbc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to connect and query.